# How to mount webdav inside QEMU

Tags: linux-mint, qemu

I run the VM using

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -accel kvm,thread=multi -cpu host -smp 2 -m 4096 -drive file=mint20.3.qcow2,if=virtio \
-machine vmport=off \
-vga qxl -usb -device usb-tablet \
-spice port=5900,addr=127.0.0.1,disable-ticketing \
-device virtio-serial-pci \
-chardev spicevmc,id=spicechannel0,debug=0,name=vdagent \
-device virtserialport,chardev=spicechannel0,name=com.redhat.spice.0 \
-device virtserialport,chardev=charchannel1,id=channel1,name=org.spice-space.webdav.0 \
-chardev spiceport,name=org.spice-space.webdav.0,id=charchannel1
```

The access the VM using `remote-viewer spice://127.0.0.1:5900`

Then in the remote viewer I click:

File > Preference > Share folder > Choose a folder from the Host

Then In the host I click:
Nemo >  Network > Spice client folder

Then the directory is mounted and I can share files between guest and host.

I want to get rid of the clicks.

I think to mount a drive I have to use something like

mount -t davfs https://cs10.cloud.com:2078 /mnt/webdav

But I am not understanding what URL shall i use after `mount -t davfs` and what will the command actually look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found on https://www.spinics.net/lists/spice-devel/msg43458.html

To quote:

> This command uses a kernel filesystem driver. I'm not sure how that
> works, as SPICE webdav doesn't generally use that. When you're
> mounting in a GNOME desktop UI, it uses 'GIO' to mount it.
>
> If you're logged into your sesssion, you can do that using
>
> gio mount dav+sd://Spice%2520folder._webdav._tcp.local/
>
> You can use 'gio mount --list' to confirm that URL, after mounting it
> from the UI.
>
> The actual mount appears in /run/user/$UID/gvfs/$URL where $URL is the
> same as the URL given to 'gio mount'